# Non-Metrizability of Compact-Open Topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, function-spaces

Let $X$ be a compact metric space and let $Y$ be a non-metrizable topological space.  How can we show that $C(X,Y)$ with compact-open topology is non-metrizable?

I was thinking of embedding $Y$ into $C(X,Y)$ via $y\mapsto E_y$ where $E_y$ is the evaluation map $f\mapsto f(y)$.  Then arguing by contradiction.  However, that's as far as I've gotten.

Comment: Note that the evaluation map is not an element of $C(X, Y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the evaluation map, which maps $C(X,Y)$ to $Y$, use the map $c$ which maps $y \in Y$ to the constant map $c(y):X\to Y$, with value $y$. This is an embedding of $Y$ into $C(X, Y)$. It’s well-defined as constant maps are continuous and $c$ is clearly 1-1 as well. Just check continuity of $c$ and its openness as a map from $Y$ onto its image. ($c^{-1}[[K,O]] = O$ and $c[O] = [X,O] \cap c[Y]$ e.g.)

Comment: So basically, for such $X$, $C(X,Y)$ is metrizable iff $Y$ is then.  Interesting!

Comment: @James_T yes you you need a metric on $Y$ to define the sup metric for the function space.